# problem with displaying data using *ngFor Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have problem with displaying data using *ngFor:

Auction object contains array of Bids.

```
export interface Auction {

  descripton: string;
  sellerId: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
  bids: Bid[];
  boughtByList: string[];
  photoAlbum: PhotoAlbumModel;
  auctionType: string;
  starts: Date;
  ends: Date;
  comments: Comment[];

}
```

```
export class Bid {

  constructor(public amount: number, public userName: string, public productTitle: string) {
  }
}
```

I getting auction data in AuctionDetailsComponent

```
export class AuctionDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private title: string;
  auction: Auction;
  bid: Bid;
  bidResponse: BidResponse;
  highestBid: number;
  coins: number;
  private paramsSubscription: Subscription;


  imageObjects: Array<object> = [];

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private productService: ProductService,
              private cartService: CartService,
              private authService: AuthenticationService,
              private auctionService: AuctionService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.title = params.title;
        this.getAuction(this.title);
      });
  }


  getAuction(title: string) {
    this.auctionService
      .get(title)
      .subscribe((auction) => {
        this.auction = auction;
        this.setImageObject();
      });
  }
```

In auction-details.component.html I try to display Bid data using *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let bid of auction.bids">
  <p>{{bid.userName}}</p>
</div>
```

Paragraphs are empty but in chrome debug there is a array.

[image]

and other Auction data - title, price displaying fine.

I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Could not reproduce with the given infos. Could you create a reproduction on stackblitz? 
Did you try to use the chrome elements inspector to check if the p tag for the userName is there?

Comment: I don't see <p> tag using chrome element inspector.

Comment: Then it would be best to make a stackblitz example, to get a quick solution

Answer (score 1):

avoid `subscribing` to the `Observable` inside `.ts` file, instead use `async pipe`, try to write it like this:

```
  async ngOnInit(): void {
    const params = await lastValueFrom(this.activatedRoute.params);
    this.title = params.title;
    this.action$ = this.auctionService.pipe(tap(() => this.setImageObject()))
  }
```

and then in the template you can use `async pipe`

```
<div *ngFor="let bid of (auction$ | async)?.bids">
 <p>{{bid.userName}}</p>
</div>
```

good luck :)

Comment: Can you explain me a little more ?
It's not about imageObject -  I can't display Auction Bids.

Comment: when I try this I have an error :  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Observable '.

Comment: my bad, I correct my answer

Comment: when I try like this ngOnInit() won't call 

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const params = await lastValueFrom(this.activatedRoute.params);
    this.title = params.title;
    this.auction$ = this.auctionService.get(this.title);
  }

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue of Async Await. Make sure to load the data before showing it on Angular app. Also, I think you can ngOnChanges lifecycle hook to load data after page is loaded.

Comment: Can you tell me a little more ? I mostly programming in Java and I only try to show results using Angular and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Use Async as mentioned in your first answer. Use async on ngOninit hook as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand when I init html Auction isn't

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.paramsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.title = params.title;
        this.getAuction(this.title);
        console.log(this.getAuction(this.title)); // undefined 
      });
  }
```

```js
getAuction(title: string) {
    this.auctionService
      .get(title)
      .then((auction) => {
        this.auction = auction;
        this.setImageObject();
      });
  }
```

I tried to change getAuction to async function but problem is still there.

```js
async get(title: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<Auction>(this.AUCTION_URL + title, this.getAuth()).toPromise();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this but ngOnInit() don't start

```js
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const params = await lastValueFrom(this.activatedRoute.params);
    this.title = params.title;
    this.auction$ = this.auctionService.get(this.title);
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3okqr.png)

Answer (score 0):

For loop don't work but when I try like this.

```js
 <div>
      <p>{{this.bids[0].userName}}</p>
   </div>
```

it's display value.

Comment: I don't think you intended this to be considered an answer. Consider editing the initial question with additional details instead